# How to store the dynamic json data from api's into a variable using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Code:

```
 exports.flightThemes=function(req,res){
    var callback = function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
    // Your error handling here
    console.log(error);
    } else {
    // Your success handling here
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    res.send(JSON.parse(data));
   }
   };

   sabre_dev_studio_flight.theme_airport_lookup('BEACH', callback);

   }
```

How can i store the dynamic json data in a variable. The data variable contains json data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the JSON with simple assignment to a local variable of that module.

So in your file, create a new variable:

```
var storeJSONData;
exports.flightThemes=function(req,res){
    var callback = function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
    // Your error handling here
    console.log(error);
    } else {
    // Your success handling here
    //Storing the data here
    storeJSONData = JSON.parse(data);
    //Using the variable now as need not parse it again
    res.send(storeJSONData);
   }
   };

   sabre_dev_studio_flight.theme_airport_lookup('BEACH', callback);

   }
```